# What are the solutions for wrapping a C-style `static const` global constant in Rust using Bindgen?

Tags: c, rust, static, ffi, rust-bindgen

I am creating Rust bindings for a C library that defines lists of standard **constant** default values:

```c
// C

typedef struct RMW_PUBLIC_TYPE rmw_qos_profile_t
{
  size_t depth;
  enum rmw_qos_reliability_policy_t reliability;
  // ...
} rmw_qos_profile_t;

enum RMW_PUBLIC_TYPE rmw_qos_reliability_policy_t
{
  RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_RELIABLE,
  RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT,
  // ...
};

// Global value that needs wrapping
static const rmw_qos_profile_t rmw_qos_profile_sensor_data =
{
  5,
  RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT,
  // ...
};
```

Using Bindgen, `static` Rust variables are generated:

```
// Rust

extern "C" {
    #[link_name = "\u{1}rmw_qos_profile_sensor_data"]
    pub static rmw_qos_profile_sensor_data: rmw_qos_profile_t;
}
```

but `static` global variables are highly inconvenient to work with in Rust, having to encase every access in an `unsafe {}` block. Especially when you do not need mutability.

I already wrapped the struct and enums in Rust:

```
// Rust

pub enum QoSReliabilityPolicy {
    Reliable = 0,
    BestEffort = 1,
}

impl From<rmw_qos_reliability_policy_t> for QoSReliabilityPolicy {
    fn from(raw: rmw_qos_reliability_policy_t) -> Self {
        match raw {
            rmw_qos_reliability_policy_t::RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_RELIABLE => QoSReliabilityPolicy::Reliable,
            rmw_qos_reliability_policy_t::RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT => QoSReliabilityPolicy::BestEffort,
        }
    }
}

pub struct QoSProfile {
    pub depth: usize,
    pub reliability: QoSReliabilityPolicy,
    // ...
}

impl From<rmw_qos_profile_t> for QoSProfile {
    fn from(qos_profile: rmw_qos_profile_t) -> Self {
        QoSProfile {
            depth: qos_profile.depth,
            reliability: qos_profile.reliability.into(),
            // ...
        }
    }
}

impl From<rmw_qos_profile_t> for QoSProfile {
    fn from(qos_profile: rmw_qos_profile_t) -> Self {
        QoSProfile {
            depth: qos_profile.depth,
            reliability: qos_profile.reliability.into(),
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am looking for a solution to expose the same pre-defined profiles, such as `rmw_qos_profile_sensor_data`, to my Rust users without having to duplicate the C values manually in Rust.

**Currently** I am duplicating the C code in Rust:

```
// Rust

// Works but unsatisfying
pub const QOS_PROFILE_SENSOR_DATA: QoSProfile = QoSProfile {
    depth: 5,
    reliability: QoSReliabilityPolicy::BestEffort,
    // ...
};
```

But this is not satisfying. When the upstream C library updates these values, users will experience inconsistent behaviour and bugs.

**What are the possible solutions for conveniently wrapping these global constants ?**

The ideal solution would:

- Automatically update the values when the upstream C library changed
- Expose global `const`s so that these values can be inlined by the compiler
- If not possible, expose global immutable variables
- If still not possible, at least not require `unsafe`

The problem that I have been facing is that, since `static const` C structures are stored in memory, they can't ben translated into a `const` so easily and this is probably why Bindgen translates it using the `static` keyword.

So, the possibilities that I can imagine, but don't know how to execute, are:

- Have smarter parsing of the C code to generate Rust code ?
- Use [some form of macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-06-macros.html) ?
- Initialize from the C lib's static memory in the prelude ?
- Initialize from the C lib's static memory explicitly ?
- Other solutions ?

Comment: Is there a key distinction between this question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748960/how-do-i-convert-a-static-global-variable-generated-by-bindgen-into-a-global-con)?

Comment: My previous question is specifically about solving a compilation error for one particular solution attempt to this problem, error which as far as I understood is not even solvable. Here, however, I am giving broader context to ask for possible design tradeoffs, of how in general such a functionality could be wrapped in Rust in a way that is performant, maintainable and convenient for the end user.

Comment: Do the memory addresses of the `static const`s matter? Can the values of the `static const`s be hard-coded into the Rust code, or can they change between C library versions?